# How to remove an appended list in drag and drop plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

here i have used Jquery UI drag and drop. how to remove the particular appended list.
Here is the html code.

```
<span> <ul id="result">Add In the list</ul></span>

<ul id="List1" class="droppable" rel="List 1">
    <p>List of tiers</p>
    <li id="tire1" class="draggable" rel="List 1">list 1</li>
    <li id="tire2" class="draggable" rel="List 2">list 2</li>
    <li id="tire3" class="draggable" rel="List 3">list 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="List2" class="droppable1 " rel="List 2">
    <p>Selected tiers</p>
</ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript code.

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#dd").remove();
            ui.draggable.attr('style', 'position:relative');
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".droppable1").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#result").append('<li id="dd">' +ui.draggable.attr('rel')+'</li>'  );
            ui.draggable.attr('style', 'position:relative');
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
});
```